# How to write event handler to setup listeners in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to write a script that will call methods in another scripts on key events. How to write it to I could specify event type (i.e. using custom `enum`), game object, script, method and arguments.
In short I need to realize similar functionality as for `Button` script:

[image: Button editor]

**For example** I choose an event *Escape*, a game object *Main camera*, my another script that attached to this game object *GameManager*, method *Exit* and its arguments (there aren't arguments in *Exit* method but it can be in others).

Is it possible to make so in the custom script?

Comment: you can add a component called . event Trigger and select some events there if that seems to help! somehow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at there is a class field of type [UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) called OnClick.  Here's the code for it:

```
public class ClickEvent : MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent OnClick;

    public void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            OnClick.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: note that you can only "reference" methods with a very basic signature namely only one parameter of one of the types `string`, numeric value, `bool` or a reference (GameObject, component) -> no enums. In the inspector. But you can simply pass the int value and cast it to your enum (`(YourEnum)passedIntValue`). There is however also `UnityEvent<>` where you can define and pass more parameters in but than all referenced methods have to implement that signature as well. Or you can in a script do e.g. `onClick.AddListener(()=>{ /*.. here you can do whatever you want so also use enums*/});`